# How to integrate Nodejs with Angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, directory-structure

Im using express framework in nodejs. My Nodejs folder structure is given below:

```
 public
      css
      js
 routes
      files.js
 views
     htmlfiles.html
 app.js
 package.json
```

I havent worked in angularjs. I need to integrate my nodejs files with angular.

My AngularJs app structure is given below:

```
app
    _config
    _helpers
    _network
    _root
      module
            pages

    app.component
    app.module
assets
environments
favicon
index.html
karma.conf
main
pollyfills
styles.css
test
tsconfig.app
tsconfig.spec
tslint
```

Can anyone please tell me how will be the folder structure if I want to do integrate nodejs with angular4?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create one angular 4 project, after that you have to set API url into 'package.json' file.
Like Blow,

```
"ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --no-serve ",
    "watch": "ng build -op dist -w",
    "api": "node server/server.js",
```

All the nodeJS file into same **angular 4** project folder inside **server** folder

so for example your directory structure will be as below,

```
--app
        --e2e
        --server
           --server.js
        --src
        --node_modules
```

I hope this solution will help.
If any problem let me know

Thanks